# How can I include an android submodule in my react-native library?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I've been able to do these two things separately:

1. Link a local Android project to my React Native app with a Native Module included (this local Android project is Open CV). My Native Module uses OpenCV code, and via Android Studio (or the settings.gradle file), I've been able to add the OpenCV project as a submodule of my Native Module and run my app successfully.
2. Create and publish a custom Native Module as a separate codebase, and use this Native Module in my app.

However, when I try doing both of these things at the same time, my app crashes because it can't find the OpenCV code. And I notice that when I `npm publish` my Native Module, the OpenCV code is definitely not being included in the tarball.

I'm not sure if I need to build it somehow or something? Not very well-versed in Android or React Native development, so apologies if I'm missing something basic here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding `api project(path: ':opencv')` to the `dependencies` block in the react *library*'s `build.gradle` (may work with `implementation project(path: ':opencv')` too), and the following to the react *app*'s `settings.gradle`:

```
def opencvsdk='path/to/opencv-4.6.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk'
include ':opencv'
project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')
```

I also currently have the above added to the *library*'s `settings.gradle` as well, though I don't think it's necessary (I added this first, it didn't do anything, and then I added it to the *app*'s `settings.gradle` and it worked. I just haven't removed it yet).